# Ruby on Rails 4 fields_for number of repetitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fields-for

I would like to display a form with four nested fieldsets for associated objects. The only way I've found is to override the `initialize` method and define four associations:

RUBY

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
  super
  4.times { items << Item.new }
end
```

and then display nested fields normally:

HAML

```
= f.fields_for :items do |item|
  = render 'item_fields', f: item
```

This is not working when I try to edit objects that already exist and have fewer number of associated items.

Any help will be appreciated.

#### MORE INFO:

```
Order has_many items
OrderSet has_many orders
```

Orders are added through the `cocoon` gem (there is at least one order in each set)

There should always be four items for each order. But when there are less items I don't want to save empty records, instead I would like to just display remaining items as empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialize is not the place as it is executed every time a new `Order` instance is created, this means: also when retrieving an existing order from the database.

Imho the view is also not the optimal place.

I would solve this in the controller:

```
def new
  @order = Order.new
  4.times { @order.items.build }
end
```

and then you can just leave your model/view as they were originally.

If you always want to show 4 nested items, you can do something similar in the edit action (to fill up to 4)

```
def edit
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  (@order.items.length...4).each { @order.items.build }
end
```

In my personal opinion this is cleaner then doing it in the view.

[EDIT: apparently it is a double nested form]

So, in your comment you clarified that it is a double-nested form, in that case, I would use the [:wrap_object](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#wrap_object) option as follows (it gets a bit hard to write a decent example here, without you giving more details, so I keep it short and hope it is clear). I am guessing you have a form for "something", with a `link_to_add_association` for `:orders`, and that order needs to have several (4) items, so you could do something like:

```
= link_to_add_association('add order', f, :orders,
:wrap_object => Proc.new { |order| 4.times { order.items.build}; order })
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible because `Order` which is parent model for `items` is further nested thus it never executes `new` action. To be more precise `orders` are dynamically added by `cocoon` gem (really nice gem thanks) to it parent model let say `OrdersSet`.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned `coocon` generates fields only based on the template, but I may be wrong.

Comment: In that case you should use the [:wrap_object](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#wrap_object) option. See the edit I made.

Comment: That looks promising. I'll report back after applying it to my code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This `:wrap_object` gives me all the power I need for solving this issue.

Comment: One more thing `@order.items << Item.new` instantly commits changes to the DB. Maybe you know some good solution?

Comment: Ow yes, indeed, but only if `@order` was already saved. You can use `@order.items.build` instead. I will adapt my post accordingly.

Comment: Completely unrelated, just curious: why are you using a default username?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74657/discussion-between-user2041318-and-nathanvda).

Answer (score 1):

Before your f.fields_for in your view, or even in your controller, you can check the length of .items() and create new objects as required:

```
(o.items.length...4).each { f.object.items << Item.new}
= f.fields_for :items do |item|
 = render 'item_fields', f: item
```

Comment: Thanks. This is nice but probably I'll stick to the @nathanvda answer because in the end I'm using his `cocoon` gem for this form.